# Scrapy: FEED_FORMAT setting ineffective?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Using Scrapy, I am not sure how to set FEED_FORMAT in settings.py.

Do I do:

```
import csv
FEED_FORMAT = csv
```

or:

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

?

Either way, I CANNOT achieve the same result as using:

```
-t csv
```

in the command line in terminal.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

should work, though you still have to add `-o file.csv` or also add [FEED_URI](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std%3asetting-FEED_URI) to settings.py

```
FEED_URI = 'file.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think it was a bug and they corrected it in 0.24.

Answer (score 0):

Works great with CrawlerProcess without using the Scrapy cli at all. You can also dictate which fields you wish to include with 'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS'.

```
class CustomSpider(Spider):
    name = 'custom_spider'
    custom_settings = {      
        'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ["url", "desc"],
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'feed-test.csv'
    }

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start_requests(self):
        ...
```